# How to sort list by many criterias

Tags: c#, sorting

I need sort list of nodes with fields: distance and frequency. I need that node with min distance and max frequency have been placed at the top. 
list.OrderByDedcending(frequency).ThenBy(distance) - not that case.

I want get average between OrderBy(distance) and orderByDescending(frequency)

Example:

```
№ Distance frequency
1 6         15
2 4         10
3 5         3
```

I don't know how explain more clearly

Comment: no example no code……

Comment: Provide some more details for more clarity

Comment: How is OrderByDedcending(frequency).ThenBy(distance) not working correctly?

Comment: Average what?  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to order by weight,just like

```
class Demo
{
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Distance:{0}  Frequency:{1}", this.Distance, this.Frequency);
    }
}

List<Demo> list = new List<Demo>
    {
        new Demo{ Distance=3, Frequency=15},
        new Demo{ Distance=4, Frequency=17},
        new Demo{ Distance=5, Frequency=3},
    };
    int[] weight = { 30, 70 };
    var tmp = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Distance * 0.3 + x.Frequency * 0.7);//there just a guess
    foreach(var q in tmp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(q);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List.sort() with a comparer that you create to fit your needs :)

```
public class ObjectBasedComparer : IComparer<ObjectType>
{
    public int Compare(ObjectType a, ObjectType b)
    {
        //Your logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how connect sort by distance and sort by frequency

Comment: you have the type of your object.  So in the logic (//insert logic here) you place the logic you want to follow.  a series of if/else to determine if "a" should be placed before (return 1) or after (return -1) "b".   if they are equals return 0.     So just hard code something what does your average/descending/multiple things